# Discussion of Biolological Literature

Tags: discussion

Is it within the scope of biology.SE to discuss specific academic literature in the biological sciences?

Are there notable limits on the aspects of the literature that may be discussed, such as the statistical methods used on specific types of data, interpretations of figures, semantics, literary conventions, practical significance of findings, statistical significance of findings, biological implications of findings, etc...

The scope of this question is not whether entire papers should be analysed in a single question, but rather what in a paper is open to biology.SE questions, and what is not.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by discussion?  Critical appraisal or discussion of specific elements of methods, results or implications *may* be within our scope but extended discussion of an entire paper is likely to be too broad for the Stack Exchange format of questions & answers

Comment: Since joining Biology SE ~ 4 months ago I have seen questions posted similar to this: "I don't understand what the term [insert term] means in the legend for Figure X in this paper [insert URL], can you please explain this to me?" To me these seem to be posted by neophytes, and the answers are relatively trivial.  Is this what you mean, questions like this?